# java codebreaker - loop won't end

Tags: java, passwords, decode

im trying to make a "codebreaker". User tries to guess random password (4 digit int)
program says if typed password is too low/high/equal. But im stuck, i cant figure out why my loop won't end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int password = 1234;
    startGame(checkNumber(loadNumber(),password));
}

public static void startGame(boolean isAWinner) {
    int lives = 5;
    do {
        loadNumber();
        lives--;
    } while (lives > 0 || !isAWinner);  //has lives or is not a winner
}

public static int loadNumber() {
    System.out.println("Type the number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int givenNumber = scan.nextInt();
    return givenNumber;
}
//check if greater,lower or equal
public static boolean checkNumber(int number, int password) {
    boolean isAWinner = false;
    if (number == password) {
        System.out.println("congratulations");
        isAWinner = true;
    }
    if (number > password) {
        System.out.println("too much");
    }
    if (number < password) {
        System.out.println("too little");
    }
    return isAWinner;
}
```

Comment: The loop will end when lives == 0 AND isAWinner == TRUE.  This is probably not what you want - use && if you want the user to have at most 5 attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your number that is loaded from user input while the game is running and assign the result to **isAWinner**.

Right now the while loop continues because **isAWinner** is never assigned a new value after an initial false value.

```
public static void startGame(boolean isAWinner) {
    int lives = 5;
    do {
        //TODO: run checkNumber on result of loadNumber and assign its result to isAWinner
        loadNumber();
        lives--;
    } while (lives > 0 || !isAWinner);  //TODO: has lives AND is not a winner
}
```

In addition, you will want your loop to continue while lives is greater than zero AND the result is not a winner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
do {
    isAWinner = checkNumber(loadNumber(), password);
    lives--;
} while (lives > 0 && !isAWinner);
```

Or else `!isAWinner` will always evaluate to true if it's not correct on the first guess. I also changed the OR to AND so that the loop will break once `lives == 0` or `isAWinner == True`.

Also I would set your `password` variable outside the main method (as a field of your class), so you can access it inside your `startGame` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code *forces* the user to be correct on the first try. Go through it step by step (you can do this with a debugger and breakpoints, or just mentally with a problem this size).

1. You call `startGame(checkNumber(loadNumber(), password));`
2. The innermost function is called first, which in this case is `loadNumber()`
3. Let's assume the user enters an *incorrect* number (4321 for example)
4. The next innermost function is called next `checkNumber(4321, 1234)` which will print "too much" then return false
5. Now, your outer function is called like this `startGame(false)` since the `checkNumber()` function returned a false to it.
6. It gives you 5 lives, then calls `loadNumber()`
7. A new number is loaded, *but a function call to check the number is never made!!*
8. This happens until lives hits 0, which is when you *expect* it to terminate, but your while condition says this: Continue to play the game if the user has lives ***OR*** if the user has not won.

Since it isn't possible to win after the first iteration, the second part of the condition will never change after the first initial incorrect guess. You can solve the original question you asked by changing your code to `while (lives > 0 && !isAWinner);` but you will still have the issue of not having checked any of the answers after the first one.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation made it much obvious to me :)